# Can't get AngularJS's $http to do cross domain requests like jQuery's "ajax"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, cors

I need to work with an API from a third-party and they sent me a test `html` file to use. I open the file in the browser like so: `file///...` and it is able to do the requests successfully by pressing some buttons that trigger the `jQuery` code. They are using `jQuery` like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
    });


$.ajax({
        beforeSend : function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
        },
        async:true,
        url        : loginUrl,
        method     : 'post',
        //cache      : false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data       : data,
        processData: true,
        success    : loginHandle,
        error      : loginError
    });
```

I am trying this in AngularJS with no luck:

```
...

$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

...

return $http.post(host+'/admin/login', {data: credentials})
    .then(complete)
    .catch(failed);
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://x.x.x.x:8080/admin/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'null'. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

Their `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `null` and their request headers have `Origin` set to `null` as well somehow.

Is there any way I can get this working at least for testing purposes? I looked at `$http.jsonp`, but it doesn't seem to support `POST` data.

**EDIT:**

I just used their `$.ajax` code inside my AngularJS file and it worked, but only with the Chome CORS plugin mentioned below. I guess when the `html` file runs in the browser with `file:///` the origin is set to `null` automatically.

Comment: That jQuery code should not work either since the CORs header is not set.

Comment: Well, it's working.

Comment: jQuery is sending a different content type than your angular request is, and this difference is enough for the browser to send a preflight for the angular request and not for the jquery one. Also... you should **never** need to set `crossDomain` to `true`. it is true by default if it is a cross domain request. All of the answers suggesting it are simply nonsense.

Comment: You need to open this file on web server not in `file://` protocol

Comment: @charlietfl i don't think that's related, since he's sending the request to something that actually is on a server, not the filesystem.

Comment: @charlietfl You are correct, I am running angularJS from a web app, I just mentioned that I ran their file in the browser intially to test it and it worked but on on my web app.

Comment: Not sure why cors is issue but your data is definitely not the sme format as @KevinB pointed out. $http default content type is `application/json`. Need to add header nd serialize data see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked with the Chrome CORS plugin, note the `$.param` function.

```
return $http({
            url: host+'/admin/login',
            data: $.param(credentials),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .then(complete)
        .catch(failed);
```